# "Group by" Link to open a popup box which displays a list of all documents under the group-by

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, view, group-by

Please can you be able to assist me.

I have been asked to configure a "Group by" link of the document library webpart, so that when users click on the hover on the link, a popup (I dont know how to call it), will appear and display a list of the documents available under that group by link.

The following is the work done:

A document library has been dropped on a page.
The view of the Document library was configured and added a Group By in order to group documents by document type.

They have requested that, when you hover on the heading of the ''document type'', a pop up displays and within the pop up box, a list/links to all documents available under that group should be shown WITHOUT 'having to open the group by Document Type link.

I have attached a little diagram.

Please can you help me. If it is not possible, is there any other way I can redesign this page please?

Thanking you so much in advance
[image]

Comment: sharepoint on premises, sharepoint online? You can do it by create own WebPart, there is no OOTB function for this, honestly i dont understand why is problem to expand this group, because what happend if there will be more documents than is able to show in the pop up?

Comment: Hi Zdenek, thanks for the response. It is SharePoint 2013. When there are a lot of documents under the group by, then the popup should have a scroll button. Is there a much more user friendly way to display these documents?

Comment: For me is the OOTB view with GroupBy the most user-friendly, cause you see here defined columns, links to documents and the mini-menu in (...) for each document. Dont understand why programing something else.

Answer (score 1):

We can use jQuery and REST API to achieve it, add the code below into script editor web part in list view page.

```
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left:180px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var listName="Policies and Procedure";
    $(".ms-listviewtable tbody[id^='titl']").each(function(){
        var policies=$(this).text().split(":")[1].split("(")[0].trim();
        var html=getDocuments(listName,policies);
        $(this).find("a").addClass("tooltip");
        $(this).find("a").append(html);
    });
})
function getDocuments(listName,filter){
    var html="<span class='tooltiptext'>";
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=FileLeafRef&$filter=Policies eq '"+filter+"'",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {          
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                html+="<p>"+item.FileLeafRef+"</p>";  
            });         
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
    html+="</span>";
    return html;
}
</script>
```

[image]